# Eliminating data field in "..." from a CSV file dataset

Tags: python, apache-spark

We are working on a program that sorts information from a data set and we want to .split() the CSV file. The problem is that the field we want to split is found in between "" and has commas. (We are already splitting commas). It is a description of a product that is useless for the project.

291,Portugal,**"Violets, truffles and ripe black fruits are present in this structured wine. It has almost too much richness, but there is plenty to admire. Solid tannins, a dark, heavy texture and complex acidity all show aging potential. Drink from 2018."**,,91,18.0,Alentejano,,,Touriga Nacional,Herdade de São Miguel

The bold part is the section we want out.

Is there a way to select an specific section? (.split("..."))

Comment: you could use the python `csv` module and it will handle this for you

Comment: as u also tagged `apache-spark`, hence I can provide pyspark way. CSV can be read in pyspark like `df = spark.read.csv('data.csv')` - this takes care of comma inside quotes.

Comment: Not clear what you want to accomplish. Are you discarding all the other info? For your example, what do you need the final form to be?

Comment: I want to discard the info INSIDE the quotes ("")

Answer (score 0):

you can use pythons `csv` module to take care of this for you

```py
data = """91,Portugal,"Violets, truffles and ripe black fruits are present in this structured wine. It has almost too much richness, but there is plenty to admire. Solid tannins, a dark, heavy texture and complex acidity all show aging potential. Drink from 2018.",,91,18.0,Alentejano,,,Touriga Nacional,Herdade de São Miguel"""

import csv
for row in csv.reader(data.splitlines()):
    row.pop(2)
    print(row)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['91', 'Portugal', '', '91', '18.0', 'Alentejano', '', '', 'Touriga Nacional', 'Herdade de São Miguel']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get_file = open("yourfile.csv","r")

read_file = get_file.read().strip().split('"""')
for i in read_file:
    print(i.split(","))

get_file.close()
```

**this another code will print without '''' **

```
get_file = open("data.csv","r")
read_file = get_file.readlines()
for i in read_file:
    num_st = i.split(",")[0][3:5]
    print(num_st)
    print("_______________")
    print(i.split(",")[1:-1])
get_file.close()
```

*just try it on your machine *

Comment: change the open("data.csv","r") to the name of your file " must be in the same directory \\\

Answer (score 0):

And welcome.

If the parts that you want will always start with `"` and nothing else will, you can check if the csv data starts with a `"` and ignore it.

```
import csv

with open('yourfile.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row.startswith('"'):
          break
        else:
          #yourcode
```